# Which datatype is appropriate for a time range in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I'm trying to set up a database for the scenario of a theme park and one of the criteria is opening hours - I'm trying to write my create table statements right now but what is the best data type for giving a range of time in this context?

Comment: Probably two columns, one for the opening time and one for the closing time.

Answer (score 2):

Either of the below:

- **DATE**
- **TIMESTAMP**

Timestamp is an extension of DATE data type. It can hold fractions of a second to a precision between 0 and 9 decimal places, the default being 6.

Create two columns:

- **opening_timestamp**
- **closing_timestamp**

Whenever you need the difference, you just need to subtract the columns. The difference between two dates is number of days.

For example, see this **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2b23/3)**.

```
create table t(id number, opening_tm date, closing_tm date);
insert into t values(1, sysdate - 4/24, sysdate + 4/24);
insert into t values(2, sysdate - 1, sysdate + 1);
commit;

select id, 
       to_char(opening_tm, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') opening_time, 
       to_char(closing_tm, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') closing_tm,
       closing_tm - opening_tm interval_in_days,
       (closing_tm - opening_tm)*24 interval_in_hours
from t;
```

Comment: If you want to substract both columns you'll need to ensure that all times belong to the same day, won't you?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario No, why? The difference between days is NUMBER OF DAYS. You just need to know the math to convert number of days to hours.

Comment: Unless the table has every day in the season in it, you'd need a 'standard' day to record against, with a nominal date; or possibly one for each day of the week depending on the requirement. There may be enough variation (special events etc.) to make a row for every day anyway. (But the date data type and two columns is still the way to go, and is the point of the question, so I'm going a bit off-topic...)

Comment: I am assuming the table would have a primary key, or some column which would differentiate the rows. In the sql fiddle, I took a leading column as `ID`.